# Tableau and BigQuery; GROUP_CONCAT not found

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api

I'm using **GROUP_CONCAT** succesfully in one of my sheets in tableau. It performs as needed and everything works.
When I publish the workbook to tableau however, I get this error:

> An unexpected error occurred. If you continue to receive this error
>   please contact your Tableau Server Administrator.
>
> **The Google BigQuery service was unable to compile the query. Function
>   not found: GROUP_CONCAT** at [1:408]  2017-02-06 11:50:35.854,
>   (WJhi5wrG0e4AACIU@woAAAHo,0,0)

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298741/function-not-found-group-concat) SO post, I should use **STRING_AGG** instead.
However if I try to use this in tableau, it doesn't recognize it as a valid function.

How could I fix this?

Comment: What is the query that you are trying to run? You should be able to use `STRING_AGG`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use STRING_AGG in your Tableau -> BigQuery data source, not as a calculated field

BigQuery Standard SQL will then understand the query and the result can be consumed in Tableau